# Adding HTML from JavaScript removes written texts from input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a web page by means of which user will add questions and answers. To add a new question the user clicks on the button and new div is added to container.

---

The problem is that when a new text-area is added, the text written in the other text-areas is removed.

---

### View of filled text-area before clicking the button

[image: before_click]

---

### View of text-area after clicking the button

[image: after_click]

---

Code:

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const template = '<form class="eachtest">' +
      '<textarea id="question" rows="4" cols="80" placeholder="Sual"></textarea>' +
      '<br><strong> A </strong> ' +
      '<textarea class="answer" rows="4" cols="80" placeholder="Cavab"></textarea><br>' +
      '</form>';

    function on_click() {
      document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML += template;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <button id="add" type="button" name="button" onclick="on_click()">add</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you should avoid using inline JS and CSS, I propose you the following:

- Create a hidden `div id="template"` in your HTML,
- Use JS to append its content after your container when you click the "add" button.
- I also changed your `id="question"` to `class="question"` as you can add multiple ones.

```js
const template = document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML;
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
document.querySelector('#add').onclick = function() {
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);
}
```

```css
#template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <button id="add" type="button" name="button">Add</button>
  <div id="template">
    <form class="eachtest"><textarea class="question" rows="4" cols="80" placeholder="Sual"></textarea><br> <strong> A </strong><textarea class="answer" rows="4" cols="80" placeholder="Cavab"></textarea><br></form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

`innerHTML` rebuild the whole content. Try the following:

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const template = '<form class="eachtest"><textarea id="question" rows="4" cols="80" placeholder="Sual"></textarea><br><strong> A </strong>  <textarea class="answer" rows="4" cols="80" placeholder="Cavab"></textarea><br></form>';

    function on_click() {
      document.querySelector('.container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

  </div>
  <button id="add" type="button" name="button" onclick="on_click()">add</button>


</body>

</html>
```

For more info on innerHTML, [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery append() :D

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const template = '<form class="eachtest"><textarea id="question" rows="4" cols="80" placeholder="Sual"></textarea><br><strong> A </strong>  <textarea class="answer" rows="4" cols="80" placeholder="Cavab"></textarea><br></form>';
      function on_click() {
        $('.container').append(template)

    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
<button id="add" type="button" name="button" onclick="on_click()">add</button>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't a jQuery qeustion. Don't use it in your answer then :) Again, its a easy way of doing it, but you should check http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/